# Echo text to multiple files using find

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-coreutils

I'd like to add some simple text into some files. Specifically, I do this on Linux lpfc drivers:

```
ls -1 /sys/class/scsi_host/host* | awk -F '@' '{system("echo 0x0 > "$1"/lpfc_log_verbose")}'
```

But thinking about common case I need to handle spaces in file names. Thus I turned to find:

```
find -L /sys/class/scsi_host -nowarn -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'lpfc_log_verbose' -exec echo 0x0 > {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

But this seems not working.

```
find -L /sys/class/scsi_host -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'lpfc_log_verbose' -exec cat {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

is fine but shows my edit didn't success. So can we use redirect in find -exec? What is the correct work-around?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> So can we use redirect in find -exec?

No, because the `> {}` is handled by Bash before invoking `find`. Technically, instead of running

```
find ... -exec echo 0x0 > {} ...
```

you could run

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'echo 0x0 > {}' ...
```

but I think it's simpler to write:

```
for dir in /sys/class/scsi_host/host* ; do
    echo 0x0 > "$dir"/lpfc_log_verbose
done
```

(which — fear not — does handle spaces and newlines and control characters).

Answer (score 5):

How about this -

```
find -L /sys/class/scsi_host -nowarn -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'lpfc_log_verbose' | 
while read -r filename; do
echo "0x0" > "$filename"
done
```

**or**

```
while read -r filename; do
echo "0x0" > "$filename"
done < <(find -L /sys/class/scsi_host -nowarn -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'lpfc_log_verbose')
```

Since `echo` is a `shell built-in` you cannot use it directly with `-exec`. However, you can do the following -

```
find -L /sys/class/scsi_host -nowarn -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'lpfc_log_verbose' -exec sh -c 'echo "0x0" > {}' \;
```

Comment: Two small points: (1) your first two examples won't work with filenames that contain newlines; (2) there exists a shell built-in named `echo`, but most systems (including the OP's) have a nearly-equivalent `echo` program in the path as well, for exactly this sort of reason.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this is to have the to_be_written content written to a temporary/dummy file and use `cp` to copy the content to the destination file, inside exec.

Use `cp` instead of `echo`.
`cp` gets interpreted correctly while echo gets enumerated a little different and hence fails to work.

`{}` inside `-exec` replaces each filename found by `find`.

```
echo 1 > /tmp/dummy
find /sys/kernel/debug/tracing -name enable -exec cp /tmp/dummy {} \;
```

Comment: Any reason for updating this?

Comment: Updated to make it more readable, as I myself found it not easy to interpret.